# Id записи в Mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

С помощью mongoose записываю в базу пользователей, у каждого из них есть уникальное id типа:

```
56e6835a90ffdc6014c728c0
```

как сделать так чтобы id было не таким длинным и без букв типа:

```
123
```

и было уникальным? Например первая запись с id:

```
1
```

а последующие увеличивались на  единицу

Comment: Зачем вам это надо?

Comment: Пользователи выводятся в таблице, для быстрого поиска и удаления используется id. Надо чтобы id было меньше (в таблице выглядит не очень хорошо). Может есть какой то метод в mongoose?

Comment: Зря минусанули, вопрос несет желание разобраться

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[newman](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/502814/id-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B8-%D0%B2-mongodb/502842#502842) неправ. **По сути это возможно**.

`MongoDB supports secondary indexes` - [отсюда](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#indexes). А не только `_id` по умолчанию.

Вам помогут эти материалы:

- Примеры схем - http://mongoosejs.com/docs/2.7.x/docs/indexes.html
- Знакомство с индексами в MongoDB - https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/indexes/

Примерный вид схемы:

```
var User = new Schema({
    name: { type: String, index: { unique: true } }
})
```

Но помните, что у вас **все равно останется нативный mongoose-овский `_id`**. В большинстве случаев для операций в базе лучше использовать его. Если стоит вопрос заботы о пользователе и читабельности - заведите отдельное поле только для пользователей, которое будет использоваться только для вывода.

Аналога уникальных инкрементируемых полей можно добиться, используя хуки (`pre` и `post`) и получив максимальный, уже существующий в коллекции идентификатор MYID. `db.COLLECTION.find({},{MYID:1}).sort({MYID:-1}).limit(1)`

Answer (score 4):

По сути это невозможно. Это системный идентиифкатор документа в коллекции Монго. И на него очень многое завязано в архитектуре mongoDB.

Если вам такой id не нравится из эстетических чувств, то вы можете добавить в документ дополнительное поле, например `user_id` и оперировать им. Т.е. самостоятельно в коде считать следующие значение при добавлении записи, показывать его в таблице и делать поиск по нему. Но при любых операциях желательней использовать системный id.

А вообще желание не очень понятно. Что-то у вас не так с логикой вашего приложения. Потому что id - это для скриптов и для базы данных. А никак не для людей.

Comment: Обоснуйте, пожалуйста, почему это невозможно - разве в элементе коллекции не может быть двух и более идентификаторов?

Comment: @MiKeBu индексы могут быть. А вот идентификаторов аналогичных тому что хочет автор вопроса - только один системный _id. Для существования других надо прикладывать дополнительные усилия - о чем собственно я и написал в своем ответе.

Comment: Во первых, автор хочет три в одном: 1) уникальный, 2) короткий, 3) автоинкрементируемый ключ. Системный `_id` не аналогичен тому, что он хочет, иначе не было бы вопроса) И, во вторых, мы с вами по разному понимаем термин **идентификатор**. Это ведь сущность для однозначной идентификации, для нее хватает одной лишь уникальности в рамках коллекции/таблицы. Для уникальности "дополнительные усилия" - это использование встроенных средств - `{ unique: true }` в схеме

Comment: @MiKeBu unique делает проверку на уникальность вновь добавляемых значений, но никак не генерирует эти значения самостоятельно.

Comment: Верно. Однако, согласитесь, факт "пароль перед сохранением в БД не генерирует хеш самостоятельно" не делает невозможным хранение хешей паролей в базе)

Answer (score 0):

**Приветствую!** Недавно столкнулся с аналогичным вопросом: необходимо было добавлять новости в БД и каждой новости присваивать id (0, 1, 2, ...). 
Т.к. mongoose присваивает каждой новости свой уникальный `_id` типа ObjectId, то решил задачу добавлением собственного поля `id` + использованием метода определения количества документов `countDocuments` в коллекции следующим образом:

```
// ...
// здесь подключение mongoose и описание newsScheme
// ...
const News = mongoose.model('news', newsScheme);

module.exports.packNewsData = async (reqBody) => {
  if (validateData(reqBody)) { // проверяет не пришла ли пустая информация от клиента
    const usersCount = await UserDB.User.countDocuments({}); // количество документов в users
    let id = 0;

    // если есть документы
    if (usersCount) {
      // найдем последний добавленный документ
      const usersLast = await UserDB.User.find().sort({ _id: -1 }).limit(1);
      // увеличим id на 1    
      id = usersCount[0].id + 1;
    }

    return {
      id,
      text: reqBody.text,
      title: reqBody.title,
      created_at: new Date(Date.now()).toUTCString()
    };
  }
  return null;
};
```

*P.S. Я тут новенький, поэтому сильно не пинайте и буду рад комментариям)*
https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.countDocuments